# Error `RSV2 and RSV3 must be clear` in `ws`

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

My app uses `ws` in Express server to serve WebSocket. I have seen a lot of errors in production:

```
RSV2 and RSV3 must be clear
/app/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:184:18getInfo  
/app/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:153:16startLoop    
/app/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:139:10add  
/app/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:142:22_ultron.on  
events.js:96:13emitOne  
events.js:188:7emit 
_stream_readable.js:176:18readableAddChunk  
_stream_readable.js:134:10Readable.push 
net.js:547:20onread
```

It seems to happen occasionally to some of my users, and I have never been able to reproduce it in my local environment.

What can I do to further investigate the root cause of this error?

Comment: I can produce this error, let me know and I can make a github gist for it

Answer (score 3):

According to [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> RSV1, RSV2, RSV3:  1 bit each
>
> MUST be 0 unless an extension is negotiated that defines meanings
> for non-zero values.  If a nonzero value is received and none of
> the negotiated extensions defines the meaning of such a nonzero
> value, the receiving endpoint MUST *Fail the WebSocket
> Connection*.

So it sounds like your server is dealing with a rogue client that's setting one of RSV2 or RSV3 (or both) without having first negotiated with the server what their meaning is.

I guess you should try to find out what client/browser they're using, and perhaps preemptively block connections made by it.